# Custom sliding menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I've seen many post here, and one helped me, but I think I miss something...

I created an ActivitySlider with that (just a sample of code)

```
public ActivitySlider(FragmentActivity activity, String loginU, String passU, String phpsessid)
{
    this.activity = activity;

    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("loginU", loginU);
    bundle.putString("passU", passU);
    bundle.putString("phpsessid", phpsessid);

    // We get the View of the Activity
    this.content = (View) activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout).getParent();
    ListView listTmp = (ListView) content.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    String[] mMenuTitles = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
    String[] tmp = {"Hello","'Suuppppp","  ?  "};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.activity, R.layout.drawer_list_item, tmp);
    listTmp.setAdapter(adapter);
    // And its parent


    // The container for the menu Fragment is added to the parent. We set an id so we can perform FragmentTransactions later on
    this.menuContainer = new FrameLayout(this.activity);

    this.menuContainer.setId(R.id.content_frame);

    // We set visibility to GONE because the menu is initially hidden
    //this.menuContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) this.content.getParent();
    parent.addView(this.menuContainer);
}

public <T extends Fragment> void setMenuFragment(Class<T> cls)
{
    Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.activity, cls.getName());
    setMenuFragment(fragment);
}

public void setMenuFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    FragmentManager manager = this.activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}`
```

So, I call this Activity in another Activity (I can't use the navigation drawer with toggle because I already have tabs) :

```
 slider = new ActivitySlider(this, loginU, passU, sessid);
 slider.setMenuFragment(MenuFragment.class);
```

That's my MenuFragment code :

```
/**
 * "Constructeur" : inflate la vue
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Récupération des arguments
    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MENU_NUMBER);
    String loginU = getArguments().getString("loginU");
    String passU = getArguments().getString("passU");
    String sessid = getArguments().getString("phpsessid");
    Log.i("MenuFrag loginU + passU",loginU + " - " + passU);

    Log.i("resArg", i + "");
    String section = "";
    View rootView = null;

    switch(i)
    {
        //Home
        case 0:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
            section = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];

            getActivity().setTitle(section);
            return rootView;
        //Demandes/Propositions
        case 1:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_viewpagertabs, container, false);
            section = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];

            getActivity().setTitle(section);

            Intent askpurp = new Intent(getActivity(),PagerWithTab.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("loginU",loginU);
            bundle.putString("passU",passU);
            bundle.putString("phpsessid",sessid);
            askpurp.putExtras(bundle);
            getActivity().startActivity(askpurp);

            return rootView;
        //Awesome
        case 2:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.awesome, container, false);
            section = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];

            getActivity().setTitle(section);
            return rootView;

        default:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.awesome2, container, false);
            section = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];

            getActivity().setTitle(section);
            return rootView;
    }
}
```

Sliding is working fine, but I've a white box on my left, and I expect my menu to be in there.  What should I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MenuFragment class cannot be used like that. Here the new MenuFragment:

```
public class MenuFrag extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menutest, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] sections = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sectionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sections);
        setListAdapter(sectionAdapter);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/wezo_color_blue"                          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can now call:

```
slider.setMenuFragment(MenuFrag.class);
```

---

The last problem to address is the menu size.  All that needs to be done is to change the following line:

```
this.content = (View) activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout).getParent();
```

to

```
this.content = (View) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();
```

If you don't do this, then it takes the actual content size (just after tabs).